# Is it possible to use Zope object database from PHP?

Tags: php, zope

as from Title.

Comment: I can't find anything on the Zope wiki that suggests it's either possible or otherwise; though I haven't posted an *answer* because I have no concrete knowledge either way. It'll be interesting to find out one way or the other.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Possible? Yes, everything is possible :)

But it is sensible? Hardly, it is too Python specific, I'm afraid, and therefore it would not be any fun to write a parser for Python data structures in PHP.

If you really need to do this, then I would recommend building a middle-layer in Python, which would then expose your ZODB over an interface that is usable in PHP. One possiblity would be using HTTP for the protocol and then JSON, XML or whatever else your heart desires for payload.

Answer (score -1):

you could call the XML-RPC interface methods from PHP